# Metaplex sign command metadata parameter

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

After creating an NFT via candy machine v2 I'm trying to execute a `sign` command [(link to the docs)](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/sign-nfts)

This is the command from the documentation:

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts sign \
    -e devnet \
    -k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json \
    -c example
```

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/master/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts#L1022) it seems that the docs do not match the implementation.

It requires an `-m/--metadata` parameter and I'm not sure what it is.
Tried to plug in a bunch of different values, but I get
`Transaction failed: Incorrect account owner` or in one case `Transaction failed: This metadata does not have creators`

What should I put as the parameter? Seems to me that it must be a public key/address of some sort, but I'm unsure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, if you use the sign command you have to add -m

When signing mints made through candy machine I would recommend using the sign-all command or metaboss though. (See metaboss.rs)